# How to flatten or postprocess a Latex generated PDF to crop image outside of viewport?

Tags: graphics, pdf, viewers, ghostscript, file-size

I have a large PDF document that includes lot of complex figures. To build these figures I used the viewport feature of the \includeGraphics command from Graphics package extensively. I am aware that cropping images like this does [not actually crop them and only asks the renderer to display them as cropped](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56936/is-it-possible-to-reduce-the-file-size-of-generated-pdf-by-clipping-the-included).

My viewports only cover rather small regions of the image. I need to reduce the size of the PDF for online publication. Are there any post processing tricks that can be applied to the PDF to flatten/recrop the images via the renderer to reduce the size? Ideally without removing vector graphics or reducing image quality.

I am aware this feature is not in Latex but it is a very important post processing optimization for the Latex viewport feature if such a workflow exists.

Comment: you say postprocess, but I think the best chance here is doing this as a pre-process to crop your images before inclusion. If they are bitmap images that should be feasible, if they are vector graphics, it depends...

Comment: Unfortunately, that would be extremely labor intensive at this point and not particularly feasible. Also, this seems like a PDF optimization that some tool probably supports and the community deserves an answer on how to post-process such PDFs.

Comment: given how the clipping is implemented I suspect a post processor would be very hard to produce, but I may be wrong, someone may have done it, already, it's a big world:-)

Comment: I don't see why it should be labour intensive at all, so long as you have a tool that can crop images. just redefine `\includegraphics` so it writes the viewports to a file, and use that file to script the clipping of all the files to the viewports.

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me redefine includegraphics to output to a file; that's a good idea.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle would you mind demonstrating how I could redefine includegraphics to achieve?